# landscape printing across browsers

Tags: css, printing

I have created a certificate that when the user hits print it needs to print in landscape.  This option works great is chrome but not in firefox or IE

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
@page { size: landscape; }
</style>
```

Does anyone know of any options?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. it works for me

```css
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    .page
    {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
     -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

could i suggest the uses of fpdf, as well s orientation options you can also change the document size, and add images. it works with co-ordinates so it is a bit of a trial and error task to start with but i use it all the time.

http://www.fpdf.org/